# Getting an error in all figway python scripts

Tags: fiware

I cloned the github project of figway in order to query the attributes of the entities to the orion but i'm getting an error in all python scripts:

```
File "GetEntity.py", line 37, in <module> 
    config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'allow_no_value'
```

I called it like -> python GetEntity.py Room

Comment: do you have the config file with all required fields properly filled? It is in the python-IDAS4 folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some tips to investigate what is going on:

- You should be using Python2.7 to run these scripts. Can you please let me know which version and OS are you using?
- We have updated FIGWAY last week. Can you please clone it again if you did it before?
- You should be using the new scripts at folder: /python-IDAS4/ContextBroker

With the previous assumptions you should get something like this (as long as that entity does not exist on that ContextBroker at the time being):

```
i6@raspberrypi ~/github/fiware-figway/python-IDAS4/ContextBroker $ python GetEntity.py Room
* Asking to http://130.206.80.40:1026/ngsi10/queryContext
* Headers: {'Fiware-Service': 'OpenIoT', 'content-type': 'application/json', 'accept': 'application/json', 'X-Auth-Token': 'NULL'}
* Sending PAYLOAD: 
{
    "entities": [
        {
            "type": "", 
            "id": "Room", 
            "isPattern": "false"
        }
    ], 
    "attributes": []
}

...

* Status Code: 200
* Response: 
{
  "errorCode" : {
    "code" : "404",
    "reasonPhrase" : "No context element found"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. I'm using CentOS6.6 on VIrtualBox and the version of python is 2.6.6. I cloned it on last thursday so i think is updated :)

Comment: i installed the version 2.7 of python but now some the imports don't work like import requests. When i try to pip install request it says it's already installed in /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages... Any sugestions?

Comment: Take a look at [virtualenv](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/). This is a super useful tool to keep your environments separated for each project. But a quick fix is to probably just remove the package and re install it.

Comment: I think you should run the pip install from the right folder. However, you may better check the python install docs at: https://docs.python.org/2/install/